# Material UI dropdown showing inappropriate height

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, react-select

I am trying to use **Material UI dropdown** in my website, using **react-select** library. The problem is, when I'm using an option longer than the dropdown width, it compromises the UI.

Can anyone please help me out here.

**Here is my react code:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import SelectDropdown from "./EditableDropdown";

export default function App() {
  const [description, setDesc] = useState("");

  const options = [
    {
      label: "a11 b33 c88 o99 t66 j44 z99",
      value: "a11 b33 c88 o99 t66 j44 z99"
    },
    {
      label: "Switches",
      value: "Switches"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "25%" }}>
      <SelectDropdown
        label="Description"
        value={description}
        onChange={setDesc}
        options={options}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Here is the code for the Editable component**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  MuiThemeProvider,
  createMuiTheme,
  MenuItem,
  Paper,
  withStyles,
  TextField
} from "@material-ui/core";
import Select from "react-select";

const styles = {
  input: {
    padding: 0,
    marginSides: "8px",
    minHeight: "inherit",
    lineHeight: "22px",
    fontWeight: 200
  },
  valueContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    fontFamily: "Helvetica Neue,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
    fontWeight: 400,
    fontSize: "14px !important"
  }
};

function inputComponent({ inputRef, ...props }) {
  return <div ref={inputRef} {...props} />;
}

function Control(props) {
  return (
    <TextField
      fullWidth
      InputProps={{
        inputComponent,
        inputProps: {
          className: props.selectProps.classes.input,
          children: props.children,
          ...props.innerProps
        }
      }}
      {...props.selectProps.textFieldProps}
    />
  );
}

function Option(props) {
  return (
    <MenuItem
      buttonRef={props.innerRef}
      selected={props.isFocused}
      component="div"
      style={{
        fontWeight: props.isSelected ? 500 : 400,
        backgroundColor: props.isSelected
          ? "rgba(59,234,31,0.2)"
          : props.isFocused
          ? "#F0F0F0"
          : null,
        fontFamily: "Helvetica Neue,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
        height: "34px",
        color: "#343434"
      }}
      {...props.innerProps}
    >
      {props.children}
    </MenuItem>
  );
}

function SingleValue(props) {
  return (
    <div
      className={props.selectProps.classes.singleValue}
      {...props.innerProps}
    >
      {typeof props.children !== "object" ? props.children : ""}
    </div>
  );
}

function ValueContainer(props) {
  let valueContainerClass = props.selectProps.classes.valueContainer;
  return (
    <div className={valueContainerClass} ref={props.inputRef}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

function Menu(props) {
  return (
    <Paper square {...props.innerProps}>
      {props.children}
    </Paper>
  );
}

const dropDownStyle = {
  overrides: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      root: {
        padding: "12px 12px 12px 16px !important"
      }
    },
    MuiInputBase: {
      root: {
        cursor: "pointer"
      }
    }
  }
};

class SelectDropdown extends React.Component {
  state = {
    focused: false
  };

  handleTextFieldChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.props.onChange({
      label: value,
      value
    });
  };

  components = {
    Control,
    Menu,
    Option,
    SingleValue,
    ValueContainer,
    IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
    DropdownIndicator: () => null
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, options, onChange, value } = this.props;

    const selectStyles = {
      clearIndicator: () => ({
        display: "none"
      }),
      noOptionsMessage: () => ({
        display: "none"
      })
    };
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme(dropDownStyle)}>
        <Select
          styles={selectStyles}
          isClearable={true}
          classes={classes}
          onChange={onChange}
          backspaceRemovesValue={true}
          textFieldProps={{
            label: this.props.label,
            variant: "outlined",
            InputLabelProps: value ? { shrink: true } : {},
            onChange: this.handleTextFieldChange
          }}
          value={value}
          components={this.components}
          isSearchable={true}
          placeholder=""
          options={options}
        />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(SelectDropdown);
```

and here is a link to same code in a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/editable-dropdown-ckf1r

Comment: I believe it is because you have `<div style={{ width: "25%" }}>` restricting the length. you may want to increase the width. Or do you mean to say, when slected and it overflows, you do not want it showing that way?

Comment: it was some time ago.. i may have tried that, with no luck.. anyways please feel free to try at your end.. with sandbox. Let me know if that works for you.. Thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: And I don't need the full width there.. I need to show a smaller input field there.<div style={{ width: "25%" }}>

Comment: I would advice you use the Material-UI Select component directly instead of the bounce through you have implemented now

Comment: Did you write the `EditableDropdown` component yourself?

Comment: Actually MUI Select didnt have the perfect UI, which i needed. So i used react-select instead, it supports material UI textfield, paper and other components too

Comment: I have initially copied the component from below. Later i modified this, to suit my need. Please check this example from Material UI official website.
https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/#react-select

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please check to see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are better off using `material-ui` directly instead of `EditableDropdown`. Since the latter has limitations.

Also you are better off using a newer version of Material-UI.

Here is a code in Material-UI (V4.9.5) that works just as you want it. If you want to add styling to it, you can always use CSS to

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

const filter = createFilterOptions();

export default function FreeSoloCreateOption() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        if (newValue && newValue.inputValue) {
          setValue({
            title: newValue.inputValue,
          });

          return;
        }

        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      filterOptions={(options, params) => {
        const filtered = filter(options, params);

        if (params.inputValue !== '') {
          filtered.push({
            inputValue: params.inputValue,
            title: `Add "${params.inputValue}"`,
          });
        }

        return filtered;
      }}
      id="free-solo-with-text-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={option => {
        // e.g value selected with enter, right from the input
        if (typeof option === 'string') {
          return option;
        }
        if (option.inputValue) {
          return option.inputValue;
        }
        return option.title;
      }}
      renderOption={option => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      freeSolo
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Free solo with text demo" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'Raiders of the Lost Ark', year: 1981 },
  { title: 'Rear Window', year: 1954 },
  { title: 'The Pianist', year: 2002 },
  { title: 'The Departed', year: 2006 },
  { title: 'Terminator 2: Judgment Day', year: 1991 },
  { title: 'Back to the Future', year: 1985 },
  { title: 'Whiplash', year: 2014 },
  { title: 'Gladiator', year: 2000 },
  { title: 'Memento', year: 2000 },
  { title: 'The Prestige', year: 2006 },
  { title: 'The Lion King', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'Apocalypse Now', year: 1979 },
  { title: 'Alien', year: 1979 },
  { title: 'Sunset Boulevard', year: 1950 },
  {
    title: 'Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb',
    year: 1964,
  },
];
```

Reference: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/
Link to code: https://codesandbox.io/s/gbljf

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I had considered of using the Autocomplete component initially, but it showed some limitations.(no custom scrollbar for dropdown, when no-options-found, it shows a new option "Add ***" and etc..). Plus i had already been using react-selct before, so i had to stick with that. I do appreciate the effort though..

Comment: So i was actually wondering, if we could do something with CSS, in order avoid over flow and show ellipses instead

Comment: Am not sure about the add option and the scroll cos I use it and all these things work perfectly. you should give it a look and try. The react-select you are using is using an outdated version of Material UI. you are honestly better off using Material-UI directly and using the styles around. the example I sent you works just as you want without much work. Give what I have sent you a try and see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks again.. I am doing a lot more functionalities, with a lot more UI styles in my project than what i have shown in the question. Also I strictly require the old MUI in my application. see.. I am working with a legacy application here, so there is no scope for a new library or changing the existing one in any case.

Comment: right! I understand. am faced with a similar challenge every now and then. let me see if I can hack soemthing for you.